# How do I change the color of a p tag based on a condition

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

If the **price_change_percentage_24h** is greater than 0, I want to change the colour of the p tags to green and if they are less than 0, I want to change it to red. I don't understand how to create the proper conditional statement and how to change the colour based on it's result. How do I achieve this?

This is the response I get from the CoinGecko API:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRINE.png

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import './Coins.css'

const CoinItem = (props) => {
  
  return (
    <div className = 'coin-row'>
        <p>{props.coins.market_cap_rank}</p>
        <div className = 'img-symbol'>
            <img src={props.coins.image} alt='' />
            <p>{props.coins.symbol.toUpperCase()}</p>

        </div>
        <p>${props.coins.current_price.toLocaleString()}</p>
        <p>{props.coins.price_change_percentage_24h.toFixed(2)}%</p>
        <p className='hide-mobile'>${props.coins.total_volume.toLocaleString()}</p>
        <p className='hide-mobile'>${props.coins.market_cap.toLocaleString()}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CoinItem
```

and

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import './App.css';
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Coins from './components/Coins'
import Coin from './routes/Coin'
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';

function App() {
  const [coins, setCoins] = useState([])
  

  const url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false';

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => {
      setCoins(response.data)
      console.log(response.data[0])
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }, [])

  return (
   <>
   <NavBar />
   <Routes>
    <Route path ='/' element={<Coins coins={coins} />} />
    <Route path='/coin' element={<Coin />}>
      <Route path=':coinId' element={<Coin />} />
    </Route>
   </Routes>
   
   </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your p tag to this,

```
<p style={{color: props.coins.price_change_percentage_24h > 0 ? "green" : "red" }}>{props.coins.price_change_percentage_24h.toFixed(2)}%</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most optimal way would be to make condition right inside of `style` with styling. In that case you are still able to not lose the styling which is granted with classes of CSS to the code.

Remember `style` "overrides" `class` properties.

```
<p class="usual_text" 
    style={ price_change_percentage_24h>0 
    ?
        {color:"green"} 
    : 
        price_change_percentage_24h<0 
        ? 
            {color:"red"} 
        : 
            {}
        }>
    props.coins.price_change_percentage_24h.toFixed(2)}%
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that to reuse all tags.

```
    import React from 'react'
import './Coins.css'

const CoinItem = (props) => {
  
  const PTag = ({children}) => {
    if (props.coins.price_change_percentage_24h > 0) {
      return <p style={{color: "green"}}>{children}</p>
    }
    return <p style={{color: "red"}}>{children}</p>
  }


  return (
    <div className = 'coin-row'>
        <PTag>{props.coins.market_cap_rank}</PTag>
        <div className = 'img-symbol'>
            <img src={props.coins.image} alt='' />
            <PTag>{props.coins.symbol.toUpperCase()}</PTag>

        </div>
        <PTag>${props.coins.current_price.toLocaleString()}</PTag>
        <PTag>{props.coins.price_change_percentage_24h.toFixed(2)}%</PTag>
        <PTag className='hide-mobile'>${props.coins.total_volume.toLocaleString()}</PTag>
        <PTag className='hide-mobile'>${props.coins.market_cap.toLocaleString()}</PTag>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CoinItem
```

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
 if (props.coins.price_change_percentage_24h > 0) {
     return (
       <p  style={{color:"green"}}></p>
     );
 else
    return (
        <p  style={{color:"red"}}></p>
     );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to put styles directly in JS, & hence would use a class or an attribute instead.

```
var pcp = props.coins.price_change_percentage_24h > 0?'pos':'neg';


<p className="hidename" data-pcp={pcp}></p>
```

And in css,

```
p[data-pcp="pos"] {
    color: springgreen;   
}

p[data-pcp="neg"] {
    color: crimson;
}
```